# Dual to Triple Monitor Setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I'm currently using a dual monitor setup with 1 video card. I'm planning on purchasing two more monitors (discarding 1, adding 2) for a total of 3 monitors. My current mobo does not have onboard video but I can use a spare video card. Here are both cards:

**Current Card**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 470

**Spare Card**: ATI Radeon HD 4850

What would be the best way to set this up? Here is what I am considering:

- Install spare video card and simply plug third monitor into it
- Install spare video card and SLI it with current card, plug third monitor into it.

Im not sure if I can or should SLI both cards or just go ahead with the first option. What should/can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you can't SLI/Crossfire link an Nvidia card with an ATI one.

As for having both cards in the machine, and simply plugging another monitor in... This should work fine. Windows 7 improves on Windows Vista's graphics architecture and allows graphics cards from different vendors.

Comment: I am currently using Windows 7 so that is good news, thanksl