# Dual monitor setup with two GPU in Linux, Pure terminal mode in one Monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have two GPUs, one of which is built-in, while the other is an Nvidia card. I would like to make one monitor connected to Nvidia to display the GUI while the other Monitor connected to the built-in GPU to show only pure terminal only access.

There were several questions from the following:

- [Dual to Triple Monitor Setup](https://superuser.com/questions/246798/dual-to-triple-monitor-setup)
- [Different backgrounds for dual monitor setup](https://superuser.com/questions/495008/different-backgrounds-for-dual-monitor-setup)
- [Dual Monitor (IGP with GPU) in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/563447/dual-monitor-igp-with-gpu-in-linux)
- [Dual Monitor with integrated and discrete GPU on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114954/dual-monitor-with-integrated-and-discrete-gpu-on-debian)
- [Three monitors with two different Nvidia cards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224709/three-monitors-with-two-different-nvidia-cards)

But so far nobody has answered this question. How can this be done?

Comment: The biggest problem you'll have with your intended configuration will be the keyboard and mouse. The Xserver will capture your keyboard and mouse as long as it's running and is being given focus, so you will not be able to 'switch' to the dedicated tty monitor. Just out of curiosity, why do you not want to use both monitors with the nVidia card? Your intended setup seems needlessly complicated to me. You could just simply set up a typical dual head configuration with the nVidia card and have one screen dedicated to a terminal emulator window.

Comment: Hi, I want to do this since my Motherboard have a build in video, and from my experience, these build in video becomes rusty if not used. I cant tell you exactly why this happens, but it does when those are not used.